# Difference between @media screen & @media only screen and

Tags: media-queries, media

When I am adding
@media screen (max-width: 480px){...}
the above seems to not work while checking for media view, but when I am applying
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){...}
the media view seems to work.

Can anyone please guide me why the above happened ?

Comment: Probably you're just missing the `and` from the first one.

Comment: I have used the @media without 'and' and 'only' before but can't recall whether it was only for max-width or both. It will be helpful to suggest me why without using and & only the media won't work. Although I haven't checked it for min-width.

Comment: If you use multiple attributes, like `screen` or `(max-width)` in conjunction with one another, you need to combine them with one of the keywords `and|only|not`.

Comment: Okay, that explains something. Then what will be the correct way to declare `@media` for only `min-width`, only `max-width` ??

Comment: If you're using `screen`, you'd say `@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {}`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (max-width:480px):
```

@media (max-width:480px) saying for a window with a max-width of 480px then the bowsers agents should apply these styles.

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px):
```

@media screen and (max-width:480px) is saying for a device that supports a 'screen' mode and a window with max-width of 480px apply the styles.

This is almost identical to the above except you are specifying 'screen' as opposed to the other available media types.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:480px)
```

The keyword ‘only’ should be used to hide style sheets from older browsers agents. Bowsers agents must process media queries starting with ‘only’ as if the ‘only’ keyword was not present.

The only keyword is used to prevent older browsers that do not support media queries with media features from applying the specified styles.